# Dynamically set default value to drop-down menu from SQL query result

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

thanks in advance

I am working in codeIgniter with PHP and I have a drop-down menu that I need to show as default value the element that is returned from MySQL query and also show the other options from drop-down as well.

somehow I need that while populating the drop-down menu, the default option is what was pulled from Database and show the other option too.
how can I implement that? thanks 
example:

```
  <td>
   <select name = "os">
     <?php 
         $item = $requests->OS;
         $oses = array(
                'Windows Server 2008',
                'Ubuntu Server',
                'Windows Server 2003'
                );   
             foreach($oses as $os=>$d){
                    echo'<option>'.$os.'</option>';
             }
     ?>
            `enter code here`</select>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your `$item` is (string, array, object?), but just add some condition there:

```
$os_id = 0;
foreach($oses as $os=>$d){
  $os_id++;
  if ($item == $os) {
    echo'<option selected value="'.$os_id.'">'.$os.'</option>';    
  } else {
    echo'<option value="'.$os_id.'">'.$os.'</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, my array is an array of strings called result so I get the OS like this $result->OS; 
I am going to try that out and see if it will work for me.
Just 1 question, what is $os_id;

Comment: still loading as default the first element on the array and not what is returned from SQL query!

Comment: so you didn't answer on my question, what is your `$item`?? do `var_dump($item);` and tell me what is output. `$os_id` - just simple values  because you must use some values for each option. you can set any you need.

Comment: Does not show anything! 
I was using $item = $request->OS; to get the OS stored in the database and OS is a table field in the database.

From my controller I called a method in my model that returns an array with all OS selected by user, in my view I need to show in a drop down menu all OS that the array has but select the one from database

Comment: blah-blah-blah... too many words, but nothing helpful. so if your `$item` is not set up, because even NULL must be dumped by `var_dump`. we can stop here. you don't handle your script well enough and must start from the beginning. debug and find where you lost your work flow. The code you published shows just that you set new array with 3 elements, and generates `select` input based on values in that array. nothing else. what does your `$item = $requests->OS;` do or must do - I have no idea, and you did not help me to figure that out.